Find records that doesn't have 1 to 1 match between a schedule and timecard table
I have a schedule table and a timecard table and I want to find all records from the schedule table when the corresponding record is not found in the timecard table.
For example the schedule table has 5 records starting from 9/30 to 10/5



ID
START DATE
END DATE
START TIME
END TIME




123456
2024-09-30
2024-09-30
8:00
16:00


123456
2024-10-01
2024-10-01
8:00
16:00


123456
2024-10-02
2024-10-02
8:00
16:00


123456
2024-10-03
2024-10-03
8:00
16:00


123456
2024-10-04
2024-10-04
8:00
16:00



The timecard table looks like this



ID
PUNCH DATE
PUNCH IN
PUNCH OUT




123456
2024-09-30
7:59
16:01


123456
2024-10-01
7:59
16:01


123456
2024-10-02
7:59
16:01


123456
2024-10-04
7:59
16:01



I've tried the following script, but I can't seem to report just the missing 10/3 record
SELECT *
FROM schedule s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM timecard t
    WHERE t.id = s.id
    AND t.[punch date] BETWEEN '2024-09-30' AND '2024-10-05'
)
AND s.[start date] BETWEEN '2024-09-30' AND '2024-10-05';

This returns date if no records were found (not even one) in the timecard table (which is good, but doesn't serve my purpose of finding just the 10/3 record), so i also tried the following script and that also doesn't help
SELECT s.*
FROM schedule s
LEFT JOIN timecard t
    ON s.id = t.id AND t.[punch date] BETWEEN '2024-09-30' AND '2024-10-05'
WHERE t.id IS NULL OR t.[punch date] IS NULL;


(1) Do you care whether or not the timecard in/out times overlap the scheduled start/end times or do you only care about the dates? (2) Do you care if timesheet in/out times only partially cover the shift start/end? (3) Can scheduled start/end times ever span midnight? For example 2300-0700?  (4) Will scheduled start/end dates ever be different? (5) If yes, do you need to check every date in that range separately? For example, if the schedule covers 5 days, but timesheet entries only cover 4 of those days, should the uncovered day be flagged?

Note that tables have rows. not records.

@TN i don't really care for time, just need to match the dates

WITH SCHEDULE(ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME)
AS
(
  SELECT 123456, CAST('2024-09-30' AS DATE), CAST('2024-09-30' AS DATE),CAST('08:00' AS TIME(0)),CAST('16:00'AS TIME(0)) UNION ALL
 SELECT 123456,     CAST('2024-10-01' AS DATE), CAST('2024-10-01' AS DATE),CAST('08:00' AS TIME(0)),CAST('16:00'AS TIME(0)) UNION ALL
 SELECT 123456,     CAST('2024-10-02' AS DATE), CAST('2024-10-02' AS DATE),CAST('08:00' AS TIME(0)),CAST('16:00'AS TIME(0)) UNION ALL
 SELECT 123456,     CAST('2024-10-03' AS DATE), CAST('2024-10-03' AS DATE),CAST('08:00' AS TIME(0)),CAST('16:00'AS TIME(0)) UNION ALL
 SELECT 123456,     CAST('2024-10-04' AS DATE), CAST('2024-10-04' AS DATE),CAST('08:00' AS TIME(0)),CAST('16:00'AS TIME(0))
), 
TIMECARD(ID,PUNCH_DATE,PUNCH_IN,PUNCH_OUT)
AS
(
  SELECT 123456,    CAST('2024-09-30' AS DATE), CAST('07:59' AS TIME(0)),CAST('16:01' AS TIME(0))UNION ALL
  SELECT 123456,    CAST('2024-10-01' AS DATE), CAST('07:59' AS TIME(0)),CAST('16:01' AS TIME(0))UNION ALL
  SELECT 123456,    CAST('2024-10-02' AS DATE), CAST('07:59' AS TIME(0)),CAST('16:01' AS TIME(0))UNION ALL
  SELECT  123456,   CAST('2024-10-04' AS DATE), CAST('07:59' AS TIME(0)),CAST('16:01' AS TIME(0))
)
SELECT S.*
FROM SCHEDULE AS S
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM TIMECARD AS TC
  WHERE S.ID=TC.ID AND TC.PUNCH_DATE BETWEEN S.START_DATE AND S.END_DATE
)

I got the result you wanted
